# Dynamics 365 Rich Text To Upload Images

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to find a way to get my rich text editor in Dynamics 365 to work so i can upload images.

I currently use **CKEDITOR** full install, which sadly does not support uploading images.There is only an external plugin for this.

I want to install TinyMCE via CDN, can anyone give me some steps for it , i would be really thankful.

I am using Dynamics 365 Online

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question. I learned something today. I gonna assume you are already using the text editor inside an iframe.

This is an old article I found describing how you can implement it: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=xrmtinymce